# i want to iterate this loop continuously untill length and x value met

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I want to iterate this loop I have given x = 0 and incremented it but loop iteration was not working for loop error

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db_files = os.listdir("/home/yashwanth/Desktop/cve/dbfiles2")
final_db_files = sorted(db_files)
os.chdir("/home/yashwanth/Desktop/cve/dbfiles2")
length = len(final_db_files)


@app.route("/cvedata", methods=["GET"])
def cvedata():
    x = 0

    for filename in range(len(final_db_files)):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(str(final_db_files[x]))
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * from {}".format(final_db_files[x]))
        cvedata = [dict(Cve_id=row[0], Description=row[1], Published_Date=row[2], Modified_Date=row[3]) for row in
                   cursor.fetchall()]
        x = x + 1
        while x >= length:
            break
        else:
            return jsonify(cvedata)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='X>X>X>X', debug=True)
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: loop should iterate... i mean x value i'm increasing so it should iterate but im getting only x[0] data

Comment: why do you need `x`? you want to for through all `final_db_files` which is for loop for, I don't get the `x` and `while` part

Comment: final_db_files is a list [ ]

Comment: im accessing that list with final_db_files[x] .... means first file in list ... so i need all files from that and i should return in json